# Blazor does not update user interface after calling a method

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I start to learn Blazor

I need to set some value from UI and call a service for data.

I write this code that call a service to load the data from sql server;

I set the parameter and call a method and this work fine, but it doesn't work the second time the interface does not update.

The list **`public List<ChipReport> chipReports`;** it does not update

Why?

Every time I call the method shouldn't the interface be automatically updated ?

This is my code

**ChipReport Page**

```
@page "/ChipsReport"

@using Data;
@inject ChipsReportService crService

<h3>ChipsReport</h3>

<input id="txtDate" type="date" required @bind-value="paramChipReport.DataIni" />

<select @bind="paramChipReport.ValueTypeId">
    <option value="42">Par </option>
    <option value="1">Par 2</option>
    <option value="36">Par 3</option>
    <option value="100">Par 4</option>
</select>

<select @bind="paramChipReport.Absolute">
    <option value="0">Inc</option>
    <option value="1">Abs</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => LoadData(paramChipReport))">Load data</button>

<br />
<hr />

@if (@chipReports == null)
{ 
    <h2>Noting</h2>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tag</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Total</th>       
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var cr in @chipReports)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@cr.Tag</td>
                    <td>@cr.DataIni.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@cr.Total</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}



@code {
    public class ParamChipReport
    {
        public DateTime DataIni { get; set; }
        public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
        public int Absolute { get; set; }
    };

    public ParamChipReport paramChipReport = new ParamChipReport();

    public List<ChipReport> chipReports;

    private async Task<List<ChipReport>> LoadData(ParamChipReport paramChipReport)
    {
        return chipReports = await crService.GetChipsReportsAsync(paramChipReport.DataIni, paramChipReport.ValueTypeId, paramChipReport.Absolute);
    }
}
```

**Method service for data in ChipReportService Class**

```
public async Task<List<ChipReport>> GetChipsReportsAsync(DateTime DataIni, int valueTypeId, int absolute)
        {
            
            var param = new SqlParameter[] 
            {
                new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@dataini", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, Value = gamingDate },
                new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@valuetypeid", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, Value = valueTypeId },
                new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@absolute", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, Value = absolute}
            };
    
            chipsReport = await _context
                           .chipsReports
                           .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE [Accounting].[usp_ChipsReportEx] @dataini, @valuetypeid, @absolute ", param)
                           .ToListAsync();
    
            return chipsReport;
        }
```

ChipReport Class

```
public class ChipReport
    {
        [Key()]
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataIni { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }      
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you load the same data every time. Describe "doesn't work the second time"

Comment: "doesn't work the second time".. It means that when I change the parameters to pass to the service that updates the query data, the data is updated in the array, but the UI does not update

Comment: Is the first successful Load also from the button-click?  Because the signature of LoadData() is all wrong for a click handler.

Comment: and which would be the right one? Why the first time work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define  `public DateTime DateIni{ get; set; }`

but you use `@bind-value="paramChipReport.DataIni"`

Also, the first parameter to the `crService.GetChipsReports` method should be `paramChipReport.DateIni`, not `paramChipReport.GamingDate`

I believe these are the only issues with your code. I've discovered the issues as
I've created a sort of repo of your code. If your code does not work after you correct the errors, I can post here my code snippet which works perfectly well.

I wonder why your compiler or run time did not notify you... What is more strange is that you said that it works the first time. Anyhow, my repo works perfectly well. If you need it, I'll post it.

Posting....

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject ChipsReportService crService

<h3>ChipsReport</h3>

<input id="txtDate" type="date" required @bind-value="paramChipReport.DateIni" />

<select @bind="paramChipReport.ValueTypeId">
    <option value="42">opt1</option>
    <option value="1">opt2</option>
    <option value="36">opt3</option>
    <option value="100">opt4</option>
</select>

<select @bind="paramChipReport.Absolute">
    <option value="0">Inc</option>
    <option value="1">Tot</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => LoadData(paramChipReport))">Load data</button>

<br />

@if (chipReports != null)
{
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Test</th>
                <th>Test1</th>
                <th>Test2</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var cr in chipReports)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@cr.Tag</td>
                    <td>@cr.Time.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@cr.Pos</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    public class ParamChipReport
    {
        public DateTime DateIni { get; set; }
        public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
        public int Absolute { get; set; }
    };

    ParamChipReport paramChipReport = new ParamChipReport();

    ChipReport[] chipReports;

    private async Task<ChipReport[]> LoadData(ParamChipReport paramChipReport)
    {

        return chipReports = await crService.GetChipsReports(paramChipReport.DateIni, paramChipReport.ValueTypeId, paramChipReport.Absolute);
    }
}
```

### ChipReport.cs

```
public class ChipReport
    {
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Pos { get; set; }
    }
```

### ChipsReportService.cs

```
public class ChipsReportService
    {
        ChipReport[] chipsReport;

        public async Task<ChipReport[]> GetChipsReports(DateTime GamingDate,int ValueTypeId, int Absolute)
        {
            if (ValueTypeId == 42)
            {
                chipsReport = new ChipReport[] { new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag1: 42 ", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="1" },
                                                          new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag2", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="2"} };
            }

            if (ValueTypeId == 1)
            {
                chipsReport = new ChipReport[] { new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag1: 1 ", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="1" },
                                                          new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag2", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="2"} };
            }

            if (ValueTypeId == 36)
            {
                chipsReport = new ChipReport[] { new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag1: 36 ", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="1" },
                                                          new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag2", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="2"} };
            }

            if (ValueTypeId == 100)
            {
                chipsReport = new ChipReport[] { new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag1: 100 ", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="1" },
                                                          new ChipReport{ Tag="My Tag2", Time=DateTime.Now, Pos="2"} };
            }

            await Task.Yield();
            return chipsReport;
        }

     
    }
```

### Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
               // Code removed for brevity's sake
                services.AddScoped<ChipsReportService>();
            }
```

Comment: I have correct the name .. can you post your complete code? Because I don't undestand. Thanks

Comment: I Try with static data and it work, but with stored procedure nothing..

Comment: Good...Solved the problems relating to Blazor re-rendering, etc. As for the stored procedure, this is something altogether different. I'm of the opinion that the stored procedure can execute fine if well-written, but I cannot verify it. You should do it. I guess I've invested much time in this question. One last thing, why do you use stored procedure? It is much more common to use Entityframework and ling. Please, mark my answer as accepted if you think it was useful to you...

Comment: I need to use the stored proceduce because it does more things and provide the perfect record set to show. It is stange that store procedure in second time don't refresh the data

Comment: What is the scope of the ChipsReportService service ? (look up in the Startup class) Could you post in your question a complete copy of the ChipsReportService service